# Where to set password on SCP?

Tags: linux

i could not find any examples on how i can set a password using scp to transfer files remotely via from command like

http://www.garron.me/en/linux/scp-linux-mac-command-windows-copy-files-over-ssh.html

currenty wrote this:

```
scp “/localFolder/localFile.txt” userName@172.11.111.345:”/RemoteFiolder/AA/”
```

Where do i enter the password on this script that wil run automatically?

Comment: Why not set up SSH keys and use that in lieu of a password?

Answer (score 3):

Generate a key using:
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"

Your public key has been saved in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. Get that key and put it into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on your remote box. To add multiple keys, add one per line.

et voilà, passwordless login available with that key (as long as you do not protect it with a password)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just enter the password this way. There is a utility though that can automate handle the "password feeding". Install the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) programm and write a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn scp “/localFolder/localFile.txt” userName@172.11.111.345:”/RemoteFiolder/AA/”

expect "yes/no" {

    send "yes\n"

    expect "*?assword" { send <your_pass>\n }

    } "*?assword" { send <your_pass>\n }

interact
```

Answer (score 1):

The password prompt cannot be automated for security reasons, but you could use public key authentication for this.

See the [ssh-keygen(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1) manual for details.